# `UnityEngine.Component.guiTexture' is obsolete:

Tags: unity-game-engine, scripting, get, components

Hello guuys I have been worling on a script for a game where a text "Press any key to continue " will pop up. I have a problem tough with one of 2 scripts I need to make the thing work.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class AlphaText : MonoBehaviour {

   public float speedFade;
   private float count;

   // Use this for initialization
   void Start () {

   }

   // Update is called once per frame
   void Update () {
      //Fade in-out press start
      count += speedFade * Time.deltaTime;

      GetComponent<GUITexture>().guiTexture.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.color = new Color(0.5f,0.5f,0.5f,Mathf.Sin(count)*0.5f);

  }
 }
```

So my question is how is this still an error: ** CS0619: `UnityEngine.Component.guiTexture' is obsolete:`Property guiTexture has been deprecated. Use GetComponent() instead. (UnityUpgradable)'
**

I think I did use the GetComponent<>() corectly so I have no idea what to do?
Could somebody lend a hand?
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: First of all, do not use `guiTexture` is deprecated. See the duplication question for more information. Secondly, do not use `GUITexture`. If you want to display image, use `Image` or `RawImage` component.  You didn't mention what you are doing so it's impossible to make a recommendation.